# how broad is the term "chipset"?

Tags: integrated-circuit, circuit-design, semiconductors, chip-design

Can I use the term "chipset supplier" to refer generically to companies that provide packaged semiconductor chips?

Or, should "chipset" only be used to describe companies that manufacture a set of chips for a specific application (e.g. motherboard, cell phone, etc.)?

For example, if a IC vendor designs and sells an FPGA, and nothing else related to the board it goes on, is that IC vendor a chipset vendor? Where is the dividing line?

Comment: I think there's some level of ambiguity in many of these terms so you've got a bit of freedom, personally I only ever called northbridges and southbridges "chipsets". It's a bit like 'store vs. shop'. I think most people just call them IC vendors or simply 'vendors'

Comment: In math, a set may contain a single element (or even zero elements, if it is the empty set). But to non-mathematicians, there is an expectation that a set contains more than 1 of something. I agree with the other answers, but nowadays any two (or more) chips that are specifically designed to work together could probably be called a chipset. GPS chipset consisting of a GPS module and an active antenna, for example. For me, the FPGA vendor would not be a chipset vendor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Can I use the term "chipset supplier" to refer generically to companies that provide packaged semiconductor chips?"

You can of course do anything you want, but I call a bundle chips a chipset when they are much more usefull together (boarding on being absolutely useless without each other). This in contrast to more general chips, that can be used alone or in combination with many other chips.

See it this way: a chipset is only a chipset (different chips) because it is not (yet) practical to integrate them all on one die.

A telltale sign of a typical chipset is that the manufacturer doesn't put much effeort in describing the separate chips, but just tells you to connect them in this very specific way, and then goes on to tell you how that combination works. Exactly like he had preferred them to be one chip.

"if a IC vendor designs and sells an FPGA, and nothing else related to the board it goes on, is that IC vendor a chipset vendor?"

If another manufacturer sold a memory chip that was specifically designed to interface to (only?) that FPGA you could call the two chips a chipset. But in that case I would not call either one a chipset manufacturer because neither one sells the complete set.

"Where is the dividing line?"

See Toms comment. Where is the dividing line between a hill and a mountain?

Answer (score 3):

My understanding of "Chipset" comes from the days where it was literally a set of chips to support a given primary chip, i.e. a x86 CPU (Intel or AMD) and the accompanying Northbridge and Southbridge. The northbridge was the memory controller + high-bandwidth interface(s) (AGP, PCIe, etc.), and the south bridge was the slower I/O.

Modern parts, the northbridge has disappeared to become integrated onto the CPU die (integrated memory controller, PCIe root complex, etc.), and the south bridge, at least in Intel land, has been renamed Platform Controller Hub (PCH). It has extra PCIe lanes, and any I/O to the CPU that isn't PCIe (SATA, USB, etc.), plus interfaces to LPC and the SPI BootROM.

For a FPGA, I suppose you could consider the associated flash memory that holds its bitstream (for SRAM parts) together with the FPGA as a "chipset" but IMO, that is not a valid usage of the term as the SPI memory is not very complex.

For say a cellular system, you could consider the SoC, baseband processor and associated circuitry as a "chipset" as well -- without that combination of ICs, it's not a complete system. The SoC on its own is a very powerful, general-purpose processor but without the associated baseband IC, it's not going to be particularly useful as a cellular phone.

I'd reserve the term for any sufficiently advanced / high-performance ASIC that is required to be used in conjunction with another ASIC in order for the complete system to work.